# Boost asio ssl client build error?

Tags: mingw, boost-asio, libcurl, codeblocks

I'm on windows XP SP3 using codeblocks 10.05 mingw and I'm trying to build the boost asio [client ssl example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp). I tried using the following libs for compiling the file along with the linker settings.

```
    libwsock32.a  from the mingw lib
    libws2_32.a    from the mingw lib
    libboost_system-mgw44-d-1_52.a  this is what I built myself using mingw, the same version. I did this by using boost jam [http://theseekersquill.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/howto-boost-mingw/][2].

I got the next four libs from libcurl curl-7.28.1-devel-mingw32 

    libcrypto.a  
    libcrypto.dll.a
    libssl.a
    libssl.dll.a

    and the following are my linker settings:

    -lboost_system
    -lcrypto
    -lssl
```

and the following is the linker error:

```
\mingw\lib\libboost_system.a(error_code.o):error_code.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
\mingw\lib\libboost_system.a(error_code.o):error_code.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
\mingw\lib\libboost_system.a(error_code.o):error_code.cpp|| undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'|
\mingw\lib\libboost_system.a(error_code.o):error_code.cpp:(.eh_frame+0xa3)||undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

What I'm wondering is why doesn't boost include the ssl library for this or mingw for that fact and is there some way to resolve this? I know that there are two types of mingw object code SJLJ and DW2 which maybe the reason for this but I'm not sure.

This is the link for the [libcurl curl-7.28.1-devel-mingw32](http://curl.haxx.se/gknw.net/7.28.1/dist-w32/curl-7.28.1-devel-mingw32.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I put my -lboost_system-mgw44-d-1_52.a file into the mingw/lib folder and linked with `--lboost_system-mgw44-d-1_52` instead of `--libboost_system`, placed the required DLL into the project folder. Solved!